# Последовательная фильтрация данных по 3м критериям через три DropDownList

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! На текущий момент удалось реализовать три DropDownList через ViewBag в одной Ajax.BeginForm. Фильтрация работает, необходимые данные во вью выводятся. Следующим этапом я бы хотел, чтобы при выборе первого значения из любого (будем считать его первым) списка, во всех остальных списках List менялся (скрывалось лишнее, что не относится к выбранному значению). Подскажите, как это можно реализовать? Причем списки у меня во вью Index (значения в списки передается через ViewBag), а контент выводится в PartialView.

Comment: Вы все-таки опишите эту "белиберду".

Comment: изменил вопрос, предыдущую проблему решил через ViewBag, чтобы хотя бы запустить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

привет.
Если вопрос еще актуален то можно так сделать

Контролер

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Continent = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Азия"}, new SelectListItem() { Text = "Европа" } };

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Country(string continent = "")
        {
            var T = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Выберите континент" } };
            if (continent == "Азия")
            {
                T.Clear();
                T.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Китай" });
                T.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Япония" });
                T.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Гуки" });
            }
            if (continent == "Европа")
            {
                T.Clear();
                T.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Англия" });
                T.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Франция" });
                T.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Польша" });
            }
            ViewBag.Country = T;
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    List<SelectListItem> T = ViewBag.Continent;
}

<div class="col-md-4">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Country", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "countryList" }, new { id = "GetCountry" }))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("continent", T, new { @class = "form-control", id = "continent" })
    }
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="countryList">
   @Html.Partial("Country")
</div>
```

Частичное представление для отображения стран

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> C = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (ViewBag.Country != null)
    {
        C = ViewBag.Country;
    }
}
@Html.DropDownList("C", C, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

javascript

```
$('#continent').change(function () {
    $('#GetCountry').submit();
});
```

Суть такая. Выберешь континент и  он во втором списке показывает страны есть на этом континенте